# "Allow in the Background" Login items OS X Ventura Issue (NOT Notifications related)

Tags: script, launchd, plist, macos-ventura

Mac OS 13.3.1

I have a relatively simple shell script as a program argument in a LauchAgent plist that i created; it parses, loads and works just fine.

The question is, ***what does toggling the corresponding program in the "Allow in Background" dialog box actually do?*** I'm finding that toggling off my script, does not actually unload or stop the service, and the script still runs when the conditions in the plist are met (WatchPaths).

Keeping the item toggled off and restarting the system results in the same behavior, as though the service is still running (RunAtLoad is also False). If i manually unload the service, then it does finally stop executing the script.

Do i have a misunderstanding of what toggling off a background item does (if so, then WHAT does it do?) or is there a potential bug or error in my plist? I do not use a KeepAlive key in my service.

**UPDATE**

I have two other Launch Agent services that run scripts at certain intervals, i've toggled them off in settings and yet they also still run.

To me this has some concerning implications, i'm surprised nobody else has encountered this or cares.

Comment: The same question is still applicable to MacOS 14.1 Sonoma.  I'm running `launchctl print-disabled gui/501` and `launchctl print-disabled user/501` and can't tell what it's doing.